# ASP.NET WebAPI KendoUI can't update or delete data, 404 (Not Found)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm using ASP.NET WebApi in conjunction with KendoUI. Json is successfully displayed in the grid, so GET works. But I can't UPDATE, CREATE or DELETE data. Something wrong with routing.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<User>()
      .Name("Grid")
      .EnableCustomBinding(false)
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(u => u.UserName);
          columns.Bound(u => u.FullName);
          columns.Bound(u => u.Email);
          columns.Bound(u => u.Address);
          columns.Bound(u => u.Phone);
          columns.Command(c =>
          {
              c.Edit();
              c.Destroy();
          });
      })
      .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create())
      .Sortable()
      .Pageable()
      .Filterable()
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(u => u.Id);
                    model.Field(u => u.Id).Editable(false);
                })
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new{controller="users"})).Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
            .Create(create => create.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new{controller="users"})).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
            .Update(update => update.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new{controller="users"})).Type(HttpVerbs.Put))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new{controller="users"})).Type(HttpVerbs.Delete))
      )
      )

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");

        grid.dataSource.transport.options.update.url = function (data) {
            return "api/users/" + data.Id;
        };

        grid.dataSource.transport.options.destroy.url = function (data) {
            return "api/users/" + data.Id;
        };
    });
</script>
```

Chrome gives me a 404 (Not Found) error: "`DELETE http://localhost:6128/Home/api/users/2 404 (Not Found)` ". How to change url to "`http://localhost:6128/api/users/2`" without prefix Home?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your `routeconfig.cs` as :

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
 {
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute((
            name: "Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{action}/{id}",  <---Change this only
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  //this will remain same as there in your config file.
        );
 }
```

Comment: After modifying I have error HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden

Comment: @votek..there must be problem somewhere else just check carefully..there must be action named 'users' inside home controller